# Derangement where k objects stay in place

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

How many ways are there to arrange $n$ objects when $k$ stay in place?
Am I correct to assume that the answer is
$${n \choose k}\cdot\left[\frac{(n-k)!}{e}\right]$$ (where $e$ is Euler's number and $[\:]$ is the [nearest integer function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_integer_function)). Because first we have to choose which $k$ objects stay in place, and then derange the remaining options?
If so, then the answer to

> How many ways are there to rearrange 12 cards, when at most 2 cards can stay in place?

should be $$\left[\frac{12!}{e}\right] + {12 \choose 11}\cdot\left[\frac{11!}{e}\right] + {12 \choose 10}\cdot\left[\frac{10!}{e}\right]$$correct?

To my final question, the answer to

> How many six-digit numbers with the digits 1-6 are there, when all six digits have to be used and no digit shall remain at its corresponding location?

would be $$\left[\frac{6!}{e}\right]$$
because if we assume that every digit starts at its corresponding location in the number, then the question becomes 'How many ways are there to rearrange these 6 digits without them staying in place?' which is a derangement.

Am I correct in assuming that?

(Sorry in case these 'pre-solved' questions aren't welcome here)

Comment: What is 'e', is it Euler's Number?

Comment: @JaideepKhare Yes, sorry. Edited.

Comment: If $[]$ are [Gausian brackets](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianBrackets.html) then $[x] = x$ that is not what you need. Your $[\cdot]$ should be [nearest integer function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NearestIntegerFunction.html).

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. These are known as [rencontres numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rencontres_numbers).